# Why is a iFrame used for Silent Authentication?

Tags: iframe, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid

I've read on multiple pages that hidden iFrames are used for silent authentication, but I couldn't figure out yet why. What are the benefits to using an iFrame over directly sending a GET Request to the Identity Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a convenient way to get around the Single-Origin-Policy in the browser when we want to do cross-origin requests (across domains).

This was a popular approach when we didn't have the more modern CORS feature to get around the SOP-policy.

Here's some additional resources about this:

- [How to handle third-party cookie blocking in browsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reference-third-party-cookies-spas)
- [The Impact of Blocked Third-Party Cookies on WSO2 Identity Server](https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/the-impact-of-blocked-third-party-cookies-on-wso2-identity-server/)

Comment: So that means that iFrames should not be used anymore as the new CORS features allow checking sessions without them?

Comment: I think there are more modern approaches to do this, but its up to the implementer of the OAuth service on how to handle this.

Comment: That was a very thin answer. At least name some alternatives to get people started that are interested in this topic